# Android save custom Array include bitmap

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap

I try to save ArrayList< Doc > that has String and ArrayList< Bitmap >.
my saveData and loadData get errors because it not compatible with Bitmap.
I need some advice or fix my problem, thanks.

Errors

```
A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
A/.scnapplicatio: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
runtime.cc:655] All threads:
runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (19):
runtime.cc:655] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x7157cc28 self=0xe0400e10
runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=6883 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xeedc0478
runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 773111122 159407281 346 ) utm=53 stm=23 core=2 HZ=100
runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xff3a8000-0xff3aa000 stackSize=8192KB
runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

My code(structure)

```
// MainActivity
public static ArrayList<Doc> DocList;

public class Doc {
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private ArrayList<ImageModel> imageList;
}

public class ImageModel {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
}
```

My function

```
private void saveData(Object arrayTarget) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(arrayTarget);
    editor.putString("task list", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Doc>>() {}.getType();
    DocList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if (DocList == null) {
        DocList = new ArrayList<Doc>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i solved my problem again, just save picture one by one from that arraylist in some folder that specifi you to know it was that folder of that array.
in the code it will save in internal storage (data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files).

```
private void saveImageBitmap(Bitmap path){
    File path = new File(getFilesDir(), path.toString());

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```